# not able to open a url with openURL in [UIApplication sharedApplication]?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, iphone-sdk-3.0

i am trying to open a url 
(**http://c22.smaato.net/oapi/lp.jsp;jsessionid=E253E547A55290CA553F493659433DBF.c22**) 
on a button through the following code

```
NSString *strs=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[linkArry objectAtIndex:0]];



    NSURL *urls = [NSURL URLWithString:strs];



    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urls];
```

[linkArry objectAtIndex:0] is the link mentioned above.

but it is not responding?? if i type something like **"http://www.google.com"** it works..

is there any other method to open these urls??

Comment: Show the code that defines `url`.

Comment: If RespLink is a string, why are you converting it in a string in such way?

Comment: updated the correct code

Comment: please show the code that defines `linkArry`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the line

NSURL *urls = [NSURL URLWithString:strs];

NSlog("urls : %@", urls);
and print the urls in console , if you find urls is nil,

then escape the strs with NSUTF8StringEncoding.

strs = [strs stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *urls = [NSURL URLWithString:strs];

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that url is of NSURL type and not NSString